# Let $M, N$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $G=M\times N$. Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ s.t. $HM=G=HN$ and $H\cap M= H\cap N=1$. Show $M\cong N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

Question: Let $M, N$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $G=M\times N$.  Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $HM=G=HN$ and $H\cap M= H\cap N=1$.  Show $M\cong N$.

Thoughts: We have that $HM=G=HN$, and so $|HN|=|HM|\implies |H||N|=|H||M|$, since $H\cap M= H\cap N=1$.  Dividing both sides by $|H|$ gives us that $|M|=|N|$.  Now, I believe to show equality (I guess, isomorphism only), I need to show that either $M\subseteq N$ or $N\subseteq M$, since their orders are already equal.  Maybe this is just trivial?  If $N=M$, then we're done, so would I then just consider the cases when $N\subset M\subseteq G$ and $M\subset N\subseteq G$, and maybe try to use that $G=M\times N$, somehow?

Any thoughts are, as always, greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Observations: are you allowed to assume $G$ is finite? Even if so, you can't expect to prove $M = N$: consider the 3 non-trivial subgroups of the Klein four-group.

Comment: @RobArthan Ah, yes, that's a good point.  I suppose we can't assume $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $G = M \times N$, we know $M$ and $N$ both are normal in $G$, so $N \cong G/M = HM/M \cong H/(H \cap M) \cong H \cong H/(H \cap N) \cong HN/N = G/N \cong M$.

Comment: How do you know that $M,N\trianglelefteq G$?

Comment: Because $G=M \times N$, so any element of $N$ doesn't just normalize $M$, in fact it commutes with $M$.

Comment: Note, by the way, that you only need $H \cap M = H \cap N$.  You don't also need that $H \cap M = \{ 1 \}$.  Just note that the two quotient groups on either side of $H$ are equal (not just isomorphic), and the rest of the proof works.

Comment: I did notice that!  Thank you!  I really appreciate your insight!!!

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the [second isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_B_(groups)) should be some help here. Note that
$$N \simeq \frac{M\times N}{M} = \frac{HM}{M}\simeq \frac{H}{H\cap M}\simeq H $$
And similarly $M\simeq H$ so that $N\simeq H \simeq M$

Answer (score 2):

Probably $M$ will not be equal to $N$.  However, given that every $g \in G$ can be written uniquely as $h_1m$ for $h_1 \in H$ and $m \in M$, and written uniquely as $h_2n$ for $h_2 \in H$ and $n \in N$, and explicit isomorphism from $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ can be given as follows: given $m \in M$, write $m$ uniquely as $hn$ for some $h \in H$ and $n \in N$, and define $\phi(m) = n$.